# How to use deflatejs option in JSZip

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so we're passing multiple Base64 Binary Strings into JSZip to make a downloadable zip file unfortunately the size is making the browser crash

JSZip has a badly documented compression option, that I'm unable get to working

*Base64 strings are huge please look at my JSFiddles for testing:*

### **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65cJr/15/)**

```
<div><img src="base64" /></div>
<button id="btnsave" >Download Zip</button>
```

js

```
 document.getElementById ("btnsave").addEventListener ("click", downloadZip, false);
    function downloadZip() {
    var zip = new JSZip();
      zip.file("magic.gif", "base64", {base64: true, binary: true, compression: DEFLATE 
 });
```

[image: Compression]

### I'm getting an error "DEFLATE is not defined"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple

`zip.file("magic.gif", "base64", {base64: true, binary: true, compression: "DEFLATE" 
 });`

note the `"` around `DEFLATE`

Comment: Boo... it worked on the jsfiddle but still crashed on real project... would you know if i can get the same functionality out of http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/

Comment: My suggestion is don't do this with JS, compress the file(s) server side and then pass it to the user, there are to many things that can go wrong passing bytes to the end user through your or 3rd party script